# Trying to crerate an alert for eventhub throttled messages using kql

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics

I am trying to create  an alert for  throttled message in eventhub. And the query i am using is:

```
AzureMetrics
| where TimeGenerated > ago(30m)
| where MetricName == "OutgoingMessages" or MetricName == "IncomingMessages"
| extend Total_Outgoing_Messages = iif(MetricName == "OutgoingMessages", Total, 0.00)
| extend Total_Incoming_Messages = iif(MetricName == "IncomingMessages", Total, 0.00)
| summarize sum(Total_Outgoing_Messages), sum(Total_Incoming_Messages) by TimeGenerated
| extend Throttled_messages = abs(sum_Total_Incoming_Messages - sum_Total_Outgoing_Messages)
| extend condition = Throttled_messages > 10 and Throttled_messages < 25
```

I am trying to create an alert  which should be fired when throttled message  is between > 10 and < 25. My condition column is giving me either true or false

Could someone please check my kql? whether i am heading to right direction or not
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`by TimeGenerated` doesn't seem to make sense.

Either use `bin`, e.g. `by bin(TimeGenerated, 5m)`, or remove it completely, dependent on your alert logic.

---

a Syntax comment -
No need for `extend ... iif(...) ...` as a preparation for the `summarize sum(...)`.
You can simply use [sumif()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/sumif-aggfunction)